# how to perform an inner join in an optimal way

Tags: postgresql, go

I am doing a practice of Go and Postgresql to create a rest api, but I am having a doubt and it is to know how to organize the data returned from the database in a more organized and optimal way, I am trying to avoid the use of an ORM , so I was researching on the subject and the most recommended that I could find was to create anonymous structures to be able to form the data I need, but I would like to know if there is any other way to be able to do what I need or that is the only way:

```
type Project struct {
    Id_Project   int64        `json:"id_project,omitempty"`
    ...
}

type Task struct {
    Id_Task         int64     `json:"id_task,omitempty"`
    Name            string    `json:"name,omitempty"`
    State           bool      `json:"state,omitempty"`
    Id_Project      Project   `json:"id_project,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

So he performed a function so that he can obtain the data which is in the table:

```
func ListTask(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    task := &model.Task{}

    db := storage.Connection()
    tsql := `
    SELECT
        Id_Task,
        Name,
        State
    FROM
        Tasks
    WHERE
        Id_Project = @p1
    ORDER BY
        Id_Task DESC
    `

    id := chi.URLParam(r, "id_project")
    id_number, err := strconv.Atoi(id)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    rows, err := db.QueryContext(context.Background(), tsql, id_number)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    tasks := []model.Task{}

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&task.Id_Task, &task.Name, &task.State); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        tasks = append(tasks, *task)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tasks)
}
```

and the returned json data is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id_task": 1,
    "name": "todo fue nuevo",
    "id_project": {
      "start_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "end_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "user": {
        "user_role": {
          "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "user_state": {
          "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "user_creation": {
        "user_role": {
          "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "user_state": {
          "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "project_state": {
        "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

It returns all the data that the project table also contains, so not if that is the way it should bring the data, or if I will be making a mistake,

Comment: "I would like to know if there is any other way to be able to do what I need" - that depends, what is it you need to do?

Comment: I would like to know if I can bring only the data from the sql query

Comment: I'm confused because the question is "how to perform an inner join in an optimal way" and I don't see a join. Is the problem that the records associated with `Task` are empty/default values? Or is the problem that you only want to return `Task` without all the extra stuff in `Project`?

Comment: SQL queries only return data. Can you explain what you mean? Are you getting more data than you want? If so, just edit your query to only pull the data you want.

Comment: @Dean That's right, I just want homework but it brings me information that I'm not specifying

Comment: @Adrian that's the problem, in the query I specify the data I want, but it returns a lot of data that I don't specify

Comment: @cosmosmulti queries don't return data they shouldn't. If they did the entire DB would be completely unusable.

Comment: @Adrian as you can see the small query that I did does it, and the json that it returns to me is data that I have not asked for

Comment: @cosmosmulti I don't see any evidence of that. It is outputting the empty fields of the `Project`, is that what you're referring to? That has nothing to do with your SQL query.

Comment: @Adrian If that's what I mean, I don't know why it happens every time I make a request

Comment: Because your `Task` has a `Project` field. All the "extra" fields are the fields of `Project`. If you don't want them included, add a `json:"-"` tag to omit it.